# ResourceDictionary in separate library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have defined my resourceDictionary in a separate library as below

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cultures="clr-namespace:My_Localization.Cultures"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:My_Localization.Properties">

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources" ObjectType="{x:Type cultures:CultureResources}" MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CultureResourcesDS" ObjectType="{x:Type cultures:CultureResources}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have used this library from another library as below (Header of xaml only)

```
<msRibbon:RibbonTab x:Class="Ribbon.Planner.PlannerRibbon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:msRibbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="500" Header="{Binding Path=Ribbon_About, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
    >
    <Grid>
     ...
     ...
     ...
    </Grid>
```

I have added the reference of My_Localization lib and I am only changing the header. All works fine but the only problem is that in design time I have "Header="{Binding Path=Ribbon_About, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" underlined. When I hover my mouse there is hint "The resource "Resources" could not be resolved"

Why is there an error like hint in my xaml? and then why does it all work fine?

My Solution structure

1. MainExe - Contains app.xaml. I have merged the resource dictionary here. No problems in xaml since the merge dictionary exists in app.xaml
2. My_Localization - Lib containing the resource dictionary (code above)
3. Lib1 - References My_Localization and there are problems in xaml as explained
4. Lib2 - References My_Localization and there are problems in xaml as explained
5. Lib3 - References My_Localization and there are problems in xaml as explained

Comment: because It only merges the dictionaries at run-time.

Comment: I thought so but then is this correct that design time the xaml shows as though there are errors? Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a reference to the `ResourceDictionary` either in the `app.xaml` file or locally. Resources in `app.xaml` are available globally to all xaml files of the application.

For Xaml files in library projects the designer works a little differently.

At runtime it will be the `app.xaml` in the startup project that will be used for all assemblies. At designtime it will be the `app.xaml` of the local assembly.
This means, you can add a `app.xaml` file to libraies, which will only be used by the Visual Studio Designer when rendering xaml files from that specific library (Set build action of file to *Page*).

To reference a `ResourceDictionary` do this:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <!-- Other global resources -->

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ASSEMBLYNAME;component/FOLDERPATH/RDNAME.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Where ASSEMBLYNAME is the name of the assembly where the `ResourceDictionary` is (check properties of project).

Example:

Project with assembly name: "MyAssembly" and `ResourceDictionary` in folder path "Resources/RDs/MyRd.xaml"

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Resources/RDs/MyRd.xaml"
```

Comment: How can a add app.xaml to a library? Do you mean just add a class and call it app.xaml? without the app.cs?

Comment: Exactly. just the xaml part. If you add a ResourceDictionary named `app.xaml` to the root of the library project, and then change the xaml node to `<Application>` instead, then it will work.

Comment: My library is a class library hence gives an error on Application "The default namespace is not defined"

Comment: try adding this: `<Application  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">`

Comment: Just to be clear: that XAML code needs to be written into the app.xaml of the project that is using the library assembly, right?

Comment: Exactly. Then `StaticResource` references will work at design time, but not at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In `App.xaml`, you must add a `MergedDictionary` to the resources which will reference your other dictionary.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Your/Dictionary/Path.xaml" />
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: My application has atleast 5-6 libraries and in each I want to use My_Localization lib. Now these libraries do not contain app.xaml

Comment: @eranotzap Ah, I was not aware of that. OP, in which case, you should put your merged dictionary inside your `RibbonTab` Resources.

Comment: @user2837961 have you done what Mike wrote ?
How are you consuming your resources ..?

Comment: There is an easy solution when using class libraries and xaml. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the ResourceDictionary in each xaml

```
<msRibbon:RibbonTab x:Class="Ribbon.Planner.PlannerRibbon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:msRibbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="500" Header="{Binding Path=Ribbon_About, Source={StaticResource Resources}}">
    <msRibbon:RibbonTab.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/<ASSEMBLY_NAME>;component/<RESOURCES_FILE>.xaml"/>
    </msRibbon:RibbonTab.Resources>
    <Grid>
     ...
     ...
     ...
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I tried this and works but if I change the language at run-time its does not change.

Comment: @user2837961: use `DynamicResource` instead.

Comment: Does not work, I am afraid. But your solution of adding app.xml to the library works fine. I am using that.