# WinUI XAML: Using a ResourceDictionary from another project

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

In my WinUI 3 application, I am trying to use a ResourceDictionary that is located in another project.

Lets say the referenced project is `ResourceTestLib` and this library project has a folder "Styles" which has a file "_Thickness.xaml".

In the `app.xaml` file of the main application, I tried these two approaches below the "Other merged dictionaries here" comment, but none of them seem to work, i.e. that app crashes on startup with that message "Cannot locate resource ...." message.

This is my app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />

            <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ResourceTestLib;component/Styles/_Thickness.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ResourceTestLib;component/Styles/_Thickness.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I hover over the respective line, Visual Studio shows a tooltip with "Path X not found" for the first referenced `ResourceDictionary` and a "Invalid characters in path" (probably because of "application:,,,") message for the second.

I presume that WinUI XAML might be different than WPF XAML in that respect? Or even that this is not supported yet?

Comment: Windows App SDK has UWP-like XAML not WPF-like. Then to find a solution for a problem use "uwp" keyword. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/44509715/12888024

Comment: Thank you, this syntax from the related post works: Source="ms-appx:///ClassLibrary1/Styles/Custom.xaml"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pack URIs are only used in WPF.

UWP and Win UI use the ms-appx URI scheme to refer to a file that resides in another assembly so try this:

```
 <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///ResourceTestLib/Styles/_Thickness.xaml" />
```

---

More on UWP style URI schemes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes